# Clamping the ACS770 Hall sensor output to 3.3V

Tags: operational-amplifier

Could anyone please help me with my question?

I would like to measure DC current from 0 to 50 amps using ACS770 hall effect current sensor with STM32F745 MCU. The problem is Max limit of ADC of my MCU is 3.3v but ACS770 will output 4.5v at 50amps and .5V at 0 amps.

I saw one circuit to solve this kind of issue but would like to know the part no. of components that I can use.

Circuit is here:
[image]

[3.3V ADC protection](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/241537/3-3v-adc-protection/241550#241550)

Comment: use an ACSxxx for 3.3V

Comment: Thanks Marco.Yes I can use ACS758 but it need stable input voltage and has less v/amp sensitivity. Where as on ACS770, voltage can fluctuate between 4.5v to 5.5v without effecting its accuracy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That circuitry is a voltage clamping circuitry. The output is clamped to 3.3v when Analog In is over 3.3v. So, you can safely(?) ignore unmanageable current. Meantime, "Analog In" needs a resistor in series to take the current when clamped

Instead, you may use a simple resistor divider and a buffering OP amp as needed.

Here's how to catch a fish: Go to DigiKey/Mouser and search for "rail to rail" and the rail voltage you desire, and may other parameters.

---

Edit
OPA choices:  [DigiKey](https://www.digikey.com/en/products/filter/linear-amplifiers-instrumentation-op-amps-buffer-amps/687?s=N4IgjCBcoCwdIDGUBmBDANgZwKYBoQB7KAbRAGYBOAJhgFYAGEAXQIAcAXKEAZQ4CcAlgDsA5iAC%2BBMADZ4oZJHTZ8RUhUYwAHORbsukXgJHipIGXUpQFqTLgLFIZcloDs1OiALkZvq97dyVy9wVzgdEPIGaldPALD-cGowBi0YELBkzKZpLJiQ7R10gjpyMFctENKwLUTGKioqsso4kDo6V1cZKo6tairOtIG%2BnLaK5KqWzoK08ijJuj6FrUqSltqZmHJqOpbKCBK%2BiYI5ahldE8yZYvMr7suz1ZAtmLCQ07eH6a%2Bn0-33zI0AFRX5gMoHW5le6Q8rAmrA%2BaXOYQuRzG4vNL9JFBBGguaJVEwaGE4JIuhY56zTKbbbo7Y6RKyWowG5MygwRkyWqWDJcygyUngPlaaFsyijMUQ2TihgSmQyi5CmWi%2BWyxLaLYpXnisCMjzkOjozFA3KuBi%2BDIxc2CzJm9yWs2UJ62lJSmJgWQOj3O926r3HJKuTKshKWmSPMMxRXlOCWtxEuMVG3UNzixP-XIrWVxrQMaMp2isqJRG3FhiM4ta6SVqWVilgvNgVk7HZF5IbAgalMS7a6%2Bu99kZAei7bUPMFMKy2vULJDmdNufJCszmeL8ht2jT2j9mfnRcC-fO0f26sz1yKrtdReuZc7aOjwen2WCjVlJ6v8fSPqinQ9rtDjVWjBDVSw1CttEYACtFKKDDVgoD12go9tAtasUNAkVkLcP83FrbRzygz5nnadkEPwsi3CwpY0JWCi3AA-ZQP2cCaD-Sh1wYg1OJHDlGjQ9k8NIhiE34mAmLoQTyQYoNpIpV8A2AyhvnAdclJYrRBIifjoIYjtKS2MoCi2EUL0xZSwXDDjq0shDwy2Idw1iByU3fYzrhpD0QjHGJwy86IukVbyukSIKZIIILqJACLBSCjMouiXNRm8nRWmSlk-JTET4pTDoMugkKEsWPKCPChKr1KlMTWy2pAoS-kMplBqGCldxzVFIMOhtMIaggVgQE4bg%2BCEMRJHCsAYIQRRlHsNQnHAAACABrAAJAAvDIGCWtavLoLb1oCPaCk2lb9uIw6SmO7aShgc7zEu06b1u3NbvFW6UnujbqDehhdpOjIUjesc3qiYHfqu8BGDe2JbrHD7wpBv7vFlW6ojB06yjhigEfBmAgcRtoZExjo0cmTHCbJmAych-HEpe5H8fYzGlMxsB5oAWXBsAADpWY507ufJdnOa5mQhf5rnXDFjIua0KXwrlqKeYV6gud2vnIgV8guZu9XvAlhWdZxrnyAN1WFbV8HRd18wzetygFYB9W%2BoGwwAFVhEEDgAHkUDZnA0CwABXfgcFGkAAFp%2BkmqABED1RHDITxmAkMwo7IQg2DQABbNg9HMawQEEAATbhw9dEIXZAEIOAATzYUPDAD5AU6AA)

Comment: Thanks Jay.  Could you please draw me a circuit with part names for the circuit you are suggesting? I am just a hobbyist and using this on my RC plane.

Comment: I calculated if I use 2k and 5.5k resistors, it will bring 4.5v to 3.3v. Do i still need any opamp or just resistor divider is enough? Thanks.

Comment: @ninja_zx11 Thanks for not getting mad on me. :). I have to learn how to draw something on this site, or make a transition on my screen. So, let's try this: R1 & R2 in series, R1 to the sensor output, R2 to ground. R2:(R1 + R2) = 3.3 / 4.5 (k ohms would be fine), an opa in buffer/voltage follower (study please) with input connected to R1&R2 node, output to your ADC. BTW, I am violating the StackExchange expectation to help you for you are new to this site. Find and read the rules, please. Many masters can help you once you can ask questions right. Tick my ^ and check mark up there, please :)

Comment: @ninja_zx11 Your question popped late, see it now. Very good question. The "filtering" and "impedance" depends on the "load", which is the ADC input characteristics, and the accuracy you'd like to get. Y can do without the OPA, add a cap, if it works, You may add a resistor in series (a small on) on OPA output to ADC in, then a cap in shunt at ADC in , that become a LPF that backward isolates OPA seeing noise from the ADC sampling. It is not necessary most of the case, depending on OPA and ADC. The STM32 hardware manual supposed to have a guideline of how to use ADC, including layout cautions.

Comment: I found MAX4014EUK+T on digikey. Do you think I can use this OPAmp with the resistor divider as you suggested?

Comment: @ninja_zx11 That is high-speed (200Mhz GBW, study it), has drawbacks for your application, check what are the use of "parameters" for OPA criteria, please. Here are possible picks, ask me again of your particular pick, please. I added the link in the main text up there, for it goes over the space limit.

Comment: I picked two. One is MIC861YC5-TR and other is MCP6G01T-E/OT. Not sure which one is better though. Please suggest.

Comment: @ninja_zx11 MIC861 looks good for starting. Read the StackExchange rules, please. We are not supposed to question and answer on comment. The moderator is tolerating for you are new, I think.

Comment: Ouch.. Extremely sorry.

Comment: @ninja_zx11 , no worry. We are fine yet, and having a lot of fun. I wouldn't be sorry to quit. ;)

Comment: @ninja_zx11 - Hi, I know you are new here, but your use of the site is confusing & has broken site rules. You wrote an "answer" which just asked a new question (anything written in the "Your Answer" box must attempt to answer the original question) so it has been deleted. And if you had a follow-up question, then it's unclear why you have accepted an answer already, indicating that you don't need further help. I will make a chatroom for you and *jay*, as it seems you want to have a discussion. Continue the conversation there (link will appear below), **not** in the comments. Thanks.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation should be [continued in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/128543/discussion-on-answer-by-jay-clamping-the-acs770-hall-sensor-output-to-3-3v).